# ionic 2 media-capture plugin , video limit3 sec . Remove alirt after limit

Tags: ionic2

i have set video limit3 sec and after 3 sec there is an alert of maximum limit reached,

How to remove that maximum limit reached alert

Comment: Please share some code and more details would be great.

Comment: i have uploaded the files in the link below

Comment: i have uploaded the files in the link below   http://www.apparatusgroup.com/demo.zip